# is Image.getSize() make a new network request every time it is called?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to improve a dynamic sized image on my app.
I need to fetch an image's dimension so i can render `<Image />` properly,
one way to do that is to call `Image.getSize()`.

My question is:

Will `Image.getSize()` made a new network request every time the function is called?
Can it use the cached image to get the size?
Or perhaps can the `Image.getSize()` request itself cached?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use useEffect like that

```
useEffect(() => {
  Image.getSize(uri, (width, height) => {
    setWidth(width)
    setHeight(height)
  }
},[uri])
```